# Making up a list of specific numbers in Python

Tags: python, permutation

How could I create a list of all possible numbers made up of 4 digits and that only use the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6?

Comment: You need to show your attempts really as this is too broad a question. However, python [**`itertools`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) includes functions to create [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), particularly [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

Answer (score 1):

Other possible way might me to use permutations and limit the length to 4. Also, an addition check can be made to make sure if the number starts with others than zero.

```
from itertools import permutations
# Define possible choices of list 
mynums = '012346'
num4Digits = [int("".join(i)) for i in permutations(mynums, 4) if i[0] in '12346']
# Checking output
num4Digits
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
list = [x for x in range(1000,6667) 
        if "5" not in str(x) and 
        "7" not in str(x) and 
        "8" not in str(x) and 
        "9" not in str(x)]
```

`range(1000,6667)` gives you all the numbers between 1000 and 6666, and the conditionals check that each number (x) does not contain any 5, 7, 8 or 9.

*there are sure plenty of fancier ways to do it, but that works,it's more obvious, and you can put it in one line

**EDIT:**

Here's another one, a bit more complex but also working.

```
exclude = ["5","7","8","9"]
filter_func = lambda x: not(any(s in str(x) for s in exclude))
list = filter(filter_func, range(1000,6667));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`

```
it = itertools.product(*(4 * ((0,1,2,3,4,6),)))
```

This creates an iterator, something that you can loop over. Note that this creates leading zeros, if you don't want them, you must post process.

A different option would be to use `numpy`:

```
>>> templ = np.arange(6)
>>> templ[-1] += 1
>>> templ = templ * 10**np.arange(4)[::-1, None]
>>> templ = np.ix_(*templ)
>>> result=np.sum(templ).ravel()
```

This produces an array of actual numbers, here leading zeros are dropped, if you don't want shorter than 4-digit numbers, you can cut the first 6^3 elements `result[6**3:]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import itertools
stuff = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
results=[]
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
   for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
       results.append(subset)
```

Comment: This is incorrect, as it gives 1,2,3,5 digit numbers as well. Moreover all  the 4 digit numbers aren't returned.

Comment: No. This also won't do. For future try to edit your answer instead of commenting. It's much more useful and convenient that way.